# What will happen to my postgres database, if I downgrade my PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using postgres 9.5. Suppose my system postgres got downgraded into 9.2. Will my old database works with newly installed postgres as it is?(backword compatibility) Or do I have to do some manual operations?

In other words, say I have a postgres database works with the latest version. Can I use the same database in other systems which run other supported versions of postgres (but not the latest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between major releases of postgresql, you will have to export your tables and database structure to older postgres version via pg_dump and pg_dumpall utilities. Then use the older version. This is the safest way.

If downgrading is done between minor releases, then just replacing the executables when the server is down and restarting the server will be sufficient, as the data directory remains unchanged between minor releases.

Answer (score 4):

There is no supported way to downgrade PostgreSQL to a lower major release.

You will have to `pg_dumpall` with 9.5 and then try to install the dump in 9.2.

There will be error messages if the 9.5 dump uses features that were not present in 9.2 yet. In that case, edit the dump and fix it for 9.2.